# Как переопределить js к определенному jquery из двух?

Tags: javascript, dom

При добавлении новой страницы на сайт, были добавлены новые скрипты. В том числе jquery. Старые скрипты перестали отображать попапы. Как подключить этот скрипт к старому jquery?

Например, сейчас образовалось два скрипта
jquery-2.1.4.min.js
jquery.js

Ни один из которых нельзя удалить.

ЗА попапы  отвечает - pop1.js

Почему не срабатывает? Действительно ли дело в новом jquery?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как склеить два jQuery и чтобы всё не грохнулось (без возможности грохнуть старый jQuery)? Это... крайне странный вопрос.

Comment: Консоль точно должна что-то говорить по этому поводу.

Comment: А если попробовать zonejs?